# GET request in Rails with big count of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make some Rails API for a mobile app, and there is the following situation: my app will authorize using a phone number (like Viber / WhatsApp); also it can automatically detect which contacts from a phone book also have my app installed. If I understand right I should create some GET method to take array of numbers and return numbers of users which have been in my system already. There are no problem with GET method for me and arrays in GET params, but phone book of users can be very big, and sending all numbers in GET params is not good solution. How can I do it right? Should I divide numbers in parts and send first 10 numbers, then next 10 numbers etc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `POST` request instead. You don't have to always use `GET` when you're searching for stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could also optimize your query string:

```
?ph=5551112222,5552223333...
```

This at least minimizes the request size. I think Rails should give you `params[:ph]` as an array. If not then splitting the string on a comma is just one extra line of code.